# Changed Windows PATH but still getting 'php.exe is not recognized ' errormessage

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, path, xampp

I changed the PATH environment variable to: `c:\xampp\php\php.exe`

Path to zend framework: `c:\xampp\php\ZendFramework-1.11.5`

My include_path looking like this: `include_path = "C:\xampp\php\;C:\xampp\php\ZendFramework-1.11.5\library"`

So then my windows terminal statement going: `C:\xampp\php\zendframework-1.11.5\bin\zf.bat create new project quikstart`

But still I keep getting the error in the prompt that says

> "php.exe" is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

What is going on?

Comment: `PATH environment variable changed to: c:\xampp\php\php.exe`? Try Changing PATH environment variable to: `c:\xampp\php\\` instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PATH should be a directory, not a file, so you should set it to "c:\xampp\php\", not "c:\xampp\php\php.exe"

Comment: Palantir's advice is correct. Just remember to restart your command line after changing the path.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please check attach image. add path according to that. hope it will help you.